# How to list my Application in Accessibility settings in android flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am creating an App to use android Accessibility service, below is my AndroidManifest.xml files. I want the user to grant my app accessibility service permission i successfully redirected the user to Accessibility settings but my app is not listed there. can anyone help me with this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
```

this is how redirected the user to Acessibility settings

```
 Future _askAcessibilityPermission() async {
    SystemSettings.accessibility();
  }
```

Comment: Neither of those `android.permission`s are meant to be held by your app; i.e., you're not supposed to have `<uses-permission>` elements for them. Instead, they are meant to be set as the values for the `android:permission` attributes on the respective `<service>` elements in the manifest; e.g., `<service android:name=".YourAccessibilityService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" ...>`.

Comment: so this mean should i have to create service ?

Comment: Yes, both of those things – accessibility and notification listening – require your app to have implementations of specific platform `Service` classes; for accessibility it's [`AccessibilityService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService), and for notification listening it's [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService).